# Using iCloud as a "semi" multi user version?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

We are about to release a new learning game for kids. We are heavily using Core data to track the users progress.

From the Beta testers there is a repeating  request for multi users interface. We will make one in the future, but we wish to know -

If we will sync the core data DB to iCloud, Is there a way to get from iCloud the current user data and switch it back when an other user uses the app ? all based on the iCloud user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  iCloud is specifically designed to isolate the data to a single user.

If you are looking to build a multi-user data sharing then you do not want to go down that road at all.  Stick with building a restful network interface.  It is a far shorter and surer path.